# Retrieving correct position of contained rotated div

Tags: css, html, position

I have a stickynote which is added directly into the body of the html page. There is also a CSS portion that lets the stickynotes get a little bigger when one hovers over them.

Also, the stickynote is supposed to be rotated via CSS. Additionally I have some javascript code that is supposed to save the position of the stickynote before the window unloads and then retrieve the stickynote and put it in the same position in which it was before the window was unloaded. However, a problem occurs with the rotated stickynotes, so that when the stickynotes are retrieved and put back into the body their position is slightly off from the position they had before refreshing the page.(this does not happen when the stickynotes are not rotated)

In order to fix that I contained each stickynote into its own stickyContainer div, which is not rotated, so that the correct positon of the stickycontainer could be retrieved after the unload event.

html:

```
<div class="stickyContainer" style="left:20px;top:70px">
    <div class="stickyNote">
        <h1>Drag Me</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum..</p>
    </div><!--stickynote-->
</div> <!--stickycontainer-->​
```

CSS:

```
.stickyNote { 
    margin: auto;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background: yellow; /* Fallback */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EBEB00), to(#C5C500));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #C5C500, #EBEB00);
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    /*position:absolute;*/
    "zIndex": 3000;
    rotating the post it by 6 degrees to the left
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-6deg);  
    -o-transform:rotate(-6deg);  
    -moz-transform:rotate(-6deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px #000;
}

.stickyContainer {
    background-color: green;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
}

.delete {
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:120%;
}

.stickyNote p {
    font-family: "Reenie Beanie", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    width: 280px;
}

/* creating the effect when the cursor is over that item.*/
.stickyNote:hover,.stickyNote:focus{  
    -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);  
    box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);  
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);  
    -moz-transform: scale(1.25);  
    -o-transform: scale(1.25);  
    position:absolute;  
    z-index:5;  
}

.toolbar {
    text-align:right;
    font-weight:bold;
}​
```

Now however the stickynotes behave strangely:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBaj/MRQc9/): As you can see in the first jsfiddle, the (yellow) stickynote expands horizontally to fit the size of its (green)container when not hovered and when hovered the stickynote is no more contained by its container.

[jsfiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBaj/MRQc9/1/): In the second jsfiddle, where there is no stickyContainer div around the stickynote, the hover function executes correctly, for some reason the rotation does not work in the js fiddle( but it does in my project), and when there is rotation, retrieving the positon of the stickynote before unload yields slighty off results, as stated above.

Questions: What do I have to change to retrieve the correct position of the stickycontainer after refresh, and have the stickycontainer expand only as much as it need to in order to contain the stickynote div. 
And how do I get the rotation of the stickynote working, within the stickycontainer?

Comment: Two issues in your css: `"zIndex"` should be `z-index`, and on the line following that you have an uncommented comment, which is causing the rules that follow it to be ignored, and hence no rotation.

Comment: great catch! thanks. I also changed the position of the stickyContainer to absolute and the position of the stickynote to relative. Now the container just takes up as much space as it needs, no more. Do you happen to know why that works and solves my problem??